# JSOM Anonymously CAML query list items

Tags: caml-query, client-object-model, list-item, anonymous-authentication

I am attempting to query a list using CAML via JSOM and am getting the error message `The method "GetItems" of the type "List" with id "{GUID}" is blocked by the administrator on the server.` I have set the web application for anonymous, the site for anonymous use, and have checked that anonymous users have `View` permissions on the list, but I continue to get this error message. I have verified my CAML is correct because I get the correct return values when running under an authenticated user. I have come across some sources that say to toggle off [Require Use Remote Interfaces Permission](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114699/anonymous-acess-in-client-model-javascript-in-office-365-in-master-page), but that didn't resolve my problem either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add permission for the levels "Use Client Integration Features" and "Remote Interfaces"?

Comment: No, where might I find those settings? In CA?

Comment: Site settings -> Site permission -> Permission levels

Comment: Created a site permission level with the levels you suggested, but how do I assign them to Anonymous User? Looks like permissions for anon are restricted to a checkbox of CRUD actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem [here](https://sharepointinaction.wordpress.com/tag/the-method-getitems-of-the-type-list-is-blocked-by-the-administrator-on-the-server/). You have to remove the `GetItems` function from the `AnonymousRestrictedTypes` via powershell. Hope this helps others with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> In On Premise environment, we can disable the “Require Use Remote Interfaces permission” to let anonymous users access Client Object Model in Central Administration.

If it is an Online environment, you can use `SP.Site.updateClientObjectModelUseRemoteAPIsPermissionSetting` Method to do the trick.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
   var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
   var site = ctx.get_site();
   site.updateClientObjectModelUseRemoteAPIsPermissionSetting(false);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() { alert('success') },
      function() { alert('error') }
   );
}, 'sp.js');
</script>
```

Comment: Just tried the suggested solution and receive `Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.` from my callback fail method. Thoughts?